# repeating node names in nested set

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

I'm retrieving the paths of leafs and there is repeated leaf names in nested set. After executing query different paths where leaf name is repeated came joined together.

i tried to fix sql code but couldn't achieve desired result

```
foreach($leafs as $id=>$leaf) {
            $sql_fetch = 'SELECT parent.name, node.category_id '
                . 'FROM vender_category AS node, '
                . 'vender_category AS parent '
                .'WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) '
                .'AND node.name = "'.$leaf['name'].'" '
                .'ORDER BY parent.lft ';

            $venderCategories[] = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql_fetch)->queryAll();
        }
$categoryChains = array();
        foreach ($venderCategories as $key => $venderCategory) {
                $categoryChains[] = array(
                    'name' => implode(' / ', array_column($venderCategory, 'name')),
                    'category_id' => implode(array_unique( array_column($venderCategory, 'category_id'))),
                );
        }
```

this code puts leaf's path with the same name together like this

```
array ( 'name' => 'smartphone / accessories / car / accessories' );
```

and i wanted 2 leafs with the same name 'accessories' to be separate like this:

```
array ( 'name' => 'smartphone / accessories );
```

`array ( 'name' => 'car / accessories' );`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was easy, but cause i'm new to programming it was quite hard to me :)

Here my fix. just add one condition to query.

```
 $sql_fetch = 'SELECT parent.name, node.category_id '
                . 'FROM vender_category AS node, '
                . 'vender_category AS parent '
                .'WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt) '
                .'AND node.name = "'.$leaf['name'].'" '
                **.'AND node.category_id = "'.$leaf['category_id']. '" '**
                .'ORDER BY parent.lft ';
```